# Powershell script to audit hosts file on all hosts on a domain but doing OU by OU

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am new to Powershell and have been tasked with writing a script that will get-content from each hosts file in every PC and server on my domain but to be able to run it independently on each OU in AD. I then need to output to a single.csv file with computername, IP and content for each host.

Can anyone advise?

I came up with 2 lines named GetHostInfo to get content and write to an individual .csv but this is no way close to what is needed. I know I can force a script to run on each individual OU but no idea how to lay it out and report each back to a single document

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted $env:computername Copy-Item C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts C:\hosts\$env:computername.csv
```

Am I correct with this script which should run the above script I posted called `GetHostInfo` on a DC called `CH0DC01`, on domain `gelbergroup.com` on `OU GG Workstation`

```
Import-module activedirectory 

$C=get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase "ou=GG Workstation, dc=CH0DC01, dc=gelbergroup.com"| ForEach-Object {$_.Name} 

Invoke-command -computername $C -scriptblock {GetHostInfo}
```

If so where do I need the `GetHostInfo` script to be saved. I am confused as I have not given it a path in the script that will run it on the OU.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you've tried. SO is _not_ at code writing service.

Comment: I came up with 2 lines to get content and write to an individual .csv but this is no way close to what is needed. I know I can force a script to run on each individual OU but no idea how to lay it out and report each back to a single document         Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
$env:computername
Copy-Item C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts C:\hosts\$env:computername.csv

Comment: Please edit your code into your question rather than posting it as comments.

Comment: Done - Total newbie here. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:

```
# declare the Get-HostInfo function as follows
function Get-HostInfo {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
    "$env:computername"
    Copy-Item "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" "C:\hosts\$env:computername.csv"
}

# and then use it
Import-module ActiveDirectory

$searchBase = "ou=GG Workstation, dc=CH0DC01, dc=gelbergroup.com"

$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $searchBase |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Name }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock { Get-HostInfo }
```

Example 2:

```
# if you declare the Get-HostInfo function in another file,
# for example C:\scripts\functions.ps1, you can include it as follows
# this is called "dot-sourcing"

. "C:\scripts\functions.ps1"

Import-module ActiveDirectory

$searchBase = "ou=GG Workstation, dc=CH0DC01, dc=gelbergroup.com"

$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $searchBase |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Name }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock { Get-HostInfo }
```

More information about dot-sourcing: http://ss64.com/ps/source.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: You're very welcome. You can accept the answer by clicking on the green check under its votes, if you will.